# Google test users on Firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-test-lab

I have implemented [google sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) , and [anonymous sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) through firebase on my app.

Whenever I submit a new apk to google play console, google runs its tests and generates a pre-launch report, which is all nice, informative, and good.

The problem though, is that my firebase auth tab is filled with a lot of garbage anonymous users, and many different random google accounts.

Is there a way to delete these accounts? Or to specify which user should be used in the google sign-in flow?

Comment: I have a similar problem.  Every time I submit a new version, my Firebase Auth gets "<random character>.<5 digits>@gmail.com" account. Is this what you observe too?

Comment: @suztomo yup, that is what I observe as well.

Comment: Good to know. I had posted my observation in my post. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65523551/975074

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your own test Google account (username + password) for Play Store to use to run your PLR tests. Or you can write and submit a robo-script to customize the app crawl even further.

[image: PLR console]

Comment: hi. I'm having same problem. with every production apk, google play testers opens 20 accounts in my project and thats bad. how can i access that page in your screenshot? i couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the page to upload your Roboscript and/or specify sign-in credentials using the Settings tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can find it under Testing => Pre-launch report => Settings