# Android app bundle uploads create strange accounts (<characters>.<5 digits>@gmail.com) in Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-console

I have an Android app using Flutter. The app backend is Firebase. Every time I upload an app bundle to Play Store Console, somebody (some system) creates strange user accounts in my Firebase project. They are strange because the email format is always `<some characters>.<5 digits>@gmail.com`, such as `johndae.38473@gmail.com` and `nanashigonbe.83721@gmail.com`.

Here is the screenshot of the Firebase console showing the strange accounts in my development project. Google Play Store support tells me to talk to Firebase support. Firebase support said they cannot track the accounts creation.

[image: Firebase console showing strange accounts]

Does anyone know why these accounts are created every time I submit my app to Play Store Console?

Comment: Thank you for comment! Actually I posted Reddit “androiddev” forum and the moderator removed my post because it bans “help me” questions (Rule 2). They instructed me to use Stackoverflow for such questions.

Comment: Without specific code or a clear mission statement, the question is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.  Try the Firebase subreddit instead.

Comment: Thank you for comment and the reference on “What topics can I ask about here”. Firebase and Google Play Console are “software tools commonly used by programmers”. Yes I will try Firebase subreddit if I cannot get an answer.

Comment: The play store is for publishing software, not building software.  For Firebase questions, we'd need to see some code that isn't working the way you expect, or a description of a problem you're trying to solve with the provided tools.

Comment: I see. Then this question might not be a suitable Firebase question, because I don’t have any code that automatically create Gmail accounts, let alone with such strange email addresses.

Comment: That's kind of the problem - we (who are unable to see into your code and its behavior) are not equipped to address this issue.  For all we know, some hacker could be signing up with random accounts.  It's impossible to know.

Comment: Right, I know I cannot expect you to know the answer. I’m hoping this is a known behavior of some system and somebody may have observed this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These emails are caused because of Google Play Console's Pre Launch Reports which run for each version of the app you submit.

These are robots that test your app and they use these emails to log in to it. Google does this to check the quality of your app and to see if it meets the Google Play policies.

Go to "Release" > "Testing" > "Pre-Launch Report". If you watch the videos there of the robots testing your app you will see they are using the strange email addresses to log in.

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn’t find the video you described and I opted out the “Pre-launch Report” already. Your explanation makes sense.

Comment: You can find the video by going to "Details" > "Performance" > And click on a device. Then you will find the videos.