# Big difference in user count on Firebase auth and Google play console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play, google-play-console

I launched a app few weeks ago on Beta(Early Access) .My app uses firebase auth and I can see around 15 user accounts on firebase auth.I also believe that they are of different users since their names in email id are different.

But at Play console I see that user count who have installed my app is just 1. How can their be so much difference in accounts count at Firebase auth and install count at Play Console?

Comment: Most likely Google Play doesn't refresh that count so often.

Comment: Also look at the email addresses of those user in Firebase Authentication, as likely some of them were generated by Play Store's automatic pre-flight testing (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65523551/209103) for example), and those accounts are likely not counted in Play's own reporting.