# Automated test google accounts are being created by Google Play in our firebase auth

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play

We are seeing a large number of test accounts polluting our firebase auth, created by some kind of automated testing by google play. Something is signing in with google in our app multiple times a day with the same pattern email but it's always a brand new email every time.

We have fully disabled the pre-launch crash report, yet according to sentry errors being logged, something is launching the app, signing in with google, then leaving the app and leaving the new account. We are seeing 5-10, sometimes more accounts created **per day**. The accounts always match the same pattern, ie `ceceliacook.40913@gmail.com`. They always have an `installerStore` of `com.android.vending`.

I contacted firebase support but they only sent me to the FAQ page and said they were unable to help.

Is there some way to turn this off? It's becoming unmanageable and a huge annoyance.

Comment: Apparently you can specify credentials for the app to use in the settings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64285476/209103 Aside from that, I don't think it's possible to disable these tests - as they're part of Play's quality control mechanism.